# ng-option filter not working angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I'm trying display data from an array in a select using ng-options and I want filter it which is not working. I don't want to show object having billHeadShortForm=FEC & FDG

Here is my HTML

```
<select class="form-control" ng-init="getBillHeadCurrentProjWise()" ng-model="headID" ng-options="h.billHeadID as h.billHead for h in billHeadsProjWise | filter:h.billHeadShortForm!='FEC' | h.billHeadShortForm!='FDG'">
     <option value="">--Select Billing Head--</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the filter part of the `ng-options` to the following:

```
ng-options="... | filter: {billHeadShortForm: '!FEC'} | filter: {billHeadShortForm: '!FDG'}"
```

See **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/um2aoh0n/1/)**

Although, you might want to read [filter documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), and write a function to avoid piping two filters.

**Edit:**

The function could be something like that:

```
$scope.filterBillHead = function (billHead) {
    // Exclude 'FEC' and 'FDG'
    // return true if billHeadShortForm is not in the array, false otherwise
    return ['FEC', 'FDG'].indexOf(billHead.billHeadShortForm) < 0;
}
```

Template:

```
ng-options="... | filter: filterBillHead"
```

See **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/um2aoh0n/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution

```
  $scope.myFunction = function (Billhead) {
    if (Billhead.billHeadShortForm == 'FEC' || Billhead.billHeadShortForm == 'FDG' || Billhead.billHeadShortForm == 'GL') {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


  ng-options="h.billHeadID as h.billHead for h in billHeadsProjWise | filter:myFunction"
```

Comment: this is by far the best solution to this problem, to further this you could create a new angular filter that wraps the existing one with your business logic in. That way you can remove this logic from the controller and into something more apt.